# Считывание координат нажатия на карту

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Необходимо получить координаты места на карте, куда нажмёт пользователь. Пытаюсь реализовать это с помощью интерфейса **InputListener**:

```
@Override
public void onMapTap(@NonNull Map map, @NonNull Point point) {
    final Point Now_Point = new Point(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude());
    System.out.println(Now_Point);
}

@Override
public void onMapLongTap(@NonNull Map map, @NonNull Point point) {
}
```

При клике по карте получаю следующую ошибку, вместо координат:

```
W/yandex.maps: yandex::maps::mapkit::map::UriParamsConverter::convert: No 'name' attribute in object s6572237334 in layer mapj
```

Причём, такая ошибка возникает при клике на здания, а при клике в свободное место на карте (дорога, сквер) вообще ничего не происходит и не выводится.
Что нужно исправить, чтобы получать координаты любого места по клику на карту?

Comment: если добавить mapView.getMap().addInputListener(this) в onCreate, то всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Я видел похожий вопрос от разработчика [IOS](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/issues/33).
Возможный ответ: у вас добавлен GeoObjectTapListener, который возвращает true из onObjectTap, в таком случае при попадании в гео-объект(poi, остановка, дом и т.д.) InputListener.onMapTap уже не вызывается.

Вместо этого реализуйте InputListener
Пример:

```
mapView.getMap().addInputListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapTap(@NonNull Map map, @NonNull Point point) {
                Log.d("MAP_TAG", "point: " + point.getLatitude() + ", " + point.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapLongTap(@NonNull Map map, @NonNull Point point) {

            }
        });
```